# jquery- keep an image at the top of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a **root** div element and inside that div i have an image.

```html
<div id="root">
  <img id="msg"/>
</div>
```

Now using jquery i used to prepend n number of div elements inside that **root** div. The issue is that the new div elements come before the img tag. . like

```
<div id="root">
  <div id="b"></div>
  <div id="a"></div>
  <img id="msg"/>
</div>
```

But I need it to prepended div elements to appear after the img tag like

```
<div id="root">    
  <img id="msg"/>
  <div id="b"></div>
  <div id="a"></div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions as to how I can achieve this using jQuery?

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle so we can help you out better?

Comment: You are using `prepend`, you should use the `append` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$("your html").insertAfter($("#msg"));
```

Comment: Thanks for advising insertAfter() method. it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Like this maybe:

```
$("#msg").after();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `append` method instead of `prepend` like this:

```
$('#root').append('<div>Div N</div>')
```

Here is the working example in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B4HY9/2/).

And here is the documentation on [`jQuery`'s `append` method](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

Answer (score 0):

Use append() instead of prepend():

1. append() method add div after first div
2. prepend() method add div before first div.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var newDiv = $("<div>test</div>");
$('img').after(newDiv);
```